# Add a date column to a temporary table in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza, alter, temp

I am working with a temporary table in Netezza that contains the columns `id`, `gender`, `start_date`, and `end_date`. I am trying to add a new column to this table that contains a default date of `2019-01-01` for all rows. The table to which I want to add this column is a local temp table, so ALTER TABLE does not work ("Error: Operation not allowed on a temp table"). To get around this, I created a new temp table with an appropriately-named empty column, but now I find I cannot use UPDATE/SET to populate it with my date ("Error: Value too large for column"). What is the best way to alter my temp table to include a new column with my date in it? If possible, I would like to just directly modify the old temp table rather than creating a new one. Note: I do not have the necessary administrator privileges in the database I'm working in to just create a permanent table to ALTER instead.

The code that successfully created a new temp table with an empty column is:

```
DROP TABLE new_temp_table IF EXISTS;
GO
SELECT id, gender, start_date, end_date, NULL default_date
INTO TEMP TABLE new_temp_table
FROM old_temp_table;
GO
```

The code that does not work to replace the NULL values in the new column is:

```
UPDATE new_temp_table
SET default_date = '2019-01-01';
GO
```

Comment: When creating a new temp table , have you tried to put the date column value then ? `SELECT id, gender, start_date, end_date, '2019-01-01' default_date`

Comment: This also works, thank you! Your answer led to a related question about the 1000-row limit for SELECT...INTO statements that I have posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250981/how-can-i-alter-a-temporary-table-with-36-million-rows-to-add-a-new-column

Comment: Hi @KellanBaker happy to hear that... You are welcome! My suggestion is to open a new question for that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast `NULL` as the type you want:

```
SELECT id, gender, start_date, end_date,
       CAST(NULL as DATE) as default_date
INTO TEMP TABLE new_temp_table
FROM old_temp_table;
```

Netezza doesn't know what the type is, so it makes a guess.  And that guess is unlikely to be a date (I think it is an `int`).

Comment: Thank you for this answer to my question. EDIT: I subsequently noticed that the number of rows in the new table is being limited to 1000 by the SELECT INTO syntax. I looked up a few workarounds, but they are infeasible for my data, which has 36 million rows. Is there a replacement for ALTER TABLE for local temp tables (i.e., an approach that modifies the original temp table instead of creating a new one and thus avoids the SELECT INTO row limit problem)?

Comment: @KellanBaker . . . That is a separate question.

Comment: I will ask it as a separate question if preferred, but it's all the same issue for me - the answer provided doesn't succeed in resolving the question for a table of the size I'm working with. Would you prefer I make a new post or edit this question to clarify that my table has 36 million rows?

Comment: @KellanBaker . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  Stack Overflow is not an ongoing dialog.  It is a question-and-answer forum.